# PHPUnit: Mocking objects in 'Wrapper' objects

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I don't know whether this works, but I don't find any information how to do this in the documentation or similar blogs:

I want to test my class **A** with some function calls of class **B** in their:

```
class A {

    function foo() {

       B::doSomeThings();
    }
}
```

For not using the real class **B** I want to mock this class. If I Unit test my object A I only find the solution to mock this object like:

```
$mockA = $this->getMockBuilder('\A')->setMethod('foo')->getMock();

$mockA->expects($this->once())->method('foo')->will(...)
```

Is it possible to only mock the function **doSomeThings()** in class **B**

Answer (score 1):

There are some workarounds

http://miljar.github.io/blog/2014/01/29/phpunit-testing-static-calls/

or you can move to other method in A function and like

```
class A {

    function foo() {

     $this->doSomeThings();
    }

    function doSomeThings() {
       B::doSomeThings();
    }
}
```

and mock doSomeThings() function in A class